# ¿ como hacer un slider adaptáble?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Como se puede   ver  en el fragmento de código tengo  un `div class="Contenido"` dentro de este esta el `div ID="banner-inicio"`  y dentro varios `div class="slider".

Lo que sucede  es que el `div ID="banner-inicio"` tiene un alto de `75%` con respecto al `div class="contenido"` que tiene un ato de `100%` de la ventana  pero lo que en realidad  necesito es que `div ID="banner-inicio"` tenga como alto el `36.85%` del ancho de `DIV class="slider"` quiero hacerlo con **Javascript (NO JQuery)**.

Esto para que el `div ID="banner-inicio"`  no ocupe  mas espacio del necesario ya que en dispositivos móviles  el `75%` de alto  de `div ID="banner-inicio"` es demasiado.

Por cierto las imágenes de mi `slider` sus dimensiones son `1900 x 700 px` no puedo cargarlas a esta plataforma por eso solo pude letras

```js
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
var Indice = 0;

function MovSlider(orientacion) {
  var MaxSlider = slider.length;
  Indice = (orientacion == "derecha") ? Indice + 1 : Indice - 1;
  Indice = (Indice >= MaxSlider) ? 0 : Indice;
  Indice = (Indice < 0) ? MaxSlider - 1 : Indice;
  var margen = "-" + (Indice * slider[Indice].scrollWidth) + "px";
  slider[0].style.marginLeft = margen;
}
```

```css
/* ESTILOS DE INICIO*/

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Contenido {
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#banner-inicio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

#banner-inicio .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-right: -4px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.derecha,
.izquierda {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.derecha {
  right: 0px;
}

.izquierda {
  left: 0px;
}

.derecha:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.izquierda:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contenido">
  <div id="banner-inicio">
    <div class="derecha" onclick="MovSlider('derecha')">&#62;</div>
    <div class="izquierda" onclick="MovSlider('izquierda')">&#60;</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER-promo.jpg);">A</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER-cyberday17.jpg);">B</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER06.jpg);">C</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER08.jpg);">D</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER17.jpg);">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas javascript, puede hacerse directamente con CSS. Cambia en `#banner-inicio` el ancho por:

```
#banner-inicio {    
      height: 36.85vw; 
}
```

La unidad `vm` es exactamente el tanto porciento del **ancho** (w de width). Si la utilizas en el **alto** de algun elemento, vinculas el alto como una proporcion del ancho, justo lo que necesitas.

PD: Tambien hay una unidad `vh` que sirve para hacer lo mismo, con relacion a la altura del viewport (que ojo, es la window del browser, no la pantalla del dispositivo)

```js
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
var Indice = 0;

function MovSlider(orientacion) {
  var MaxSlider = slider.length;
  Indice = (orientacion == "derecha") ? Indice + 1 : Indice - 1;
  Indice = (Indice >= MaxSlider) ? 0 : Indice;
  Indice = (Indice < 0) ? MaxSlider - 1 : Indice;
  var margen = "-" + (Indice * slider[Indice].scrollWidth) + "px";
  slider[0].style.marginLeft = margen;
}
```

```css
/* ESTILOS DE INICIO*/

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Contenido {
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#banner-inicio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36.85vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

#banner-inicio .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-right: -4px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.derecha,
.izquierda {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.derecha {
  right: 0px;
}

.izquierda {
  left: 0px;
}

.derecha:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.izquierda:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contenido">
  <div id="banner-inicio">
    <div class="derecha" onclick="MovSlider('derecha')">&#62;</div>
    <div class="izquierda" onclick="MovSlider('izquierda')">&#60;</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER-promo.jpg);">A</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER-cyberday17.jpg);">B</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER06.jpg);">C</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER08.jpg);">D</div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-image: url(Imagenes/BANNER17.jpg);">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```